# Identify top k values and mark them based on their respective ranking orders

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

There is an one-dimensional array, for instance, as shown in the following. Are there any functions that can transform this array into another array, which only keeps the top 5 elements of the existing array. These five kept elements are marked as `5, 4,3,2,1` based on their respective numerical values, and other elements are just marked as `0`.

```
9.00E-05
8.74E-05
-6.67E-05
-0.000296984
-0.00016961
-7.49E-06
-0.000102942
-0.000183901
0.000206149
5.62E-05
0.000112588
5.93E-05
9.85E-05
-2.29E-05
5.08E-05
0.00015748
```

Comment: Is this mean 5 ==to the max ?

Comment: Did any of the below solutions help? Feel free to accept one, or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `numpy`. We assume your array is held in variable `arr`.

```
args = arr.argsort()
arr[args[-5:]] = range(5, 0, -1)
arr[args[:-5]] = 0

# array([ 5.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  3.,  0.,  4.,
#         0.,  0.,  2.])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution from `rank`

```
s=df.rank(ascending=False)
s.mask(s>5,0).astype(int)
Out[74]: 
0     5
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     1
9     0
10    3
11    0
12    4
13    0
14    0
15    2
Name: val, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the numbers to remain in the same order and obtain an array of tuples with the original number and rank, you could do this:

```
numbers = [ 9.00E-05, 8.74E-05, -6.67E-05, -0.000296984, -0.00016961, -7.49E-06, -0.000102942, -0.000183901, 0.000206149, 5.62E-05, 0.000112588, 5.93E-05, 9.85E-05, -2.29E-05, 5.08E-05, 0.00015748]
ranks   = { n:max(5-i,0) for (i,n) in enumerate(sorted(numbers)) }
tagged  = [ (n,ranks[n]) for n in numbers ]

# tagged will contain : [(9e-05, 0), (8.74e-05, 0), (-6.67e-05, 1), (-0.000296984, 5), (-0.00016961, 3), (-7.49e-06, 0), (-0.000102942, 2), (-0.000183901, 4), (0.000206149, 0), (5.62e-05, 0), (0.000112588, 0), (5.93e-05, 0), (9.85e-05, 0), (-2.29e-05, 0), (5.08e-05, 0), (0.00015748, 0)]
```

if the original order doesn't matter, you only need this:

```
tagged   = [ (n,max(5-i,0)) for (i,n) in enumerate(sorted(numbers)) ]

# then tagge will be : [(-0.000296984, 5), (-0.000183901, 4), (-0.00016961, 3), (-0.000102942, 2), (-6.67e-05, 1), (-2.29e-05, 0), (-7.49e-06, 0), (5.08e-05, 0), (5.62e-05, 0), (5.93e-05, 0), (8.74e-05, 0), (9e-05, 0), (9.85e-05, 0), (0.000112588, 0), (0.00015748, 0), (0.000206149, 0)]
```